# How to change the default timezone of my asp.net website in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config, timezone

I'm trying to change the default time zone of my asp.net website
and i tried the following code but it didn't work

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture="ar-JO" uiCulture="ar-JO" />
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 24):

Changing the culture does not change the time zone.  There is no way in .NET to change the time zone on a per-application basis.  It can only be changed system-wide.

Many servers set it to UTC, but the best practice is to not rely on the system time zone at all.  Never use `DateTime.Now`, `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, `DateTimeKind.Local`, etc. from a web application.

Instead, use `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, or if you must know the server's local time, use `DateTimeOffset.Now`.

If you need a particular user's local time, then you need to know their time zone, and use the functions on `TimeZoneInfo` to convert between that specific zone and UTC.

Read more [here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the time zone of the server in which your database is hosted. You cannot do it through web.config.

Having the date/time stored in UTC format is a best practice. Refer to this article below.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215446/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081507-1.aspx

Hope this helps.

(source: http://forums.asp.net/post/5060690.aspx)